# Is it correct to say “on n’aime pas le beaucoup de problèmes dans le monde?”

Tags: anglais

My concern is with the use of “le” or “les” before “beaucoup” to mean “the many problems.”

Comment: Hello Kate and welcome on French SE! Grammatically, your sentence is incorrect, and I'm not certain what you are trying to say here. Could it be "On n'aime pas beaucoup les problèmes dans le monde" (meaning "we don't like problems a lot in the world")?

Answer (score 7):

You are right guessing no article is expected before the adverb *beaucoup*.

In the phrase

> ...**the many problems** in the world.

*many* is an adjective close to *numerous* so a translation can be:

> ...***les nombreux problèmes*** du monde.